# Clicking Input on Mobile Breaks CSS Layout

Tags: css, reactjs, forms, layout, tailwind-css

I have finished a small React SPA for an upcoming novel which has a bug in production. I have two forms, separated in different components as childs of a parent section. In dev tools and in production on large screens, selecting the input triggers the focus response, as normal.

However, for some reason on mobile phones, when a user tries to click an input to enter text into the field, suddenly the Footer and other components jump to mutate and clutter the screen. The inputs still work and submit properly, however it is unlikely a user would attempt it given the appearance of the screen during the focus on attempt. I will put the parent component code, along with the two form components as well as the live website URL for any with a mobile device willing to try and help me to pinpoint the issue. Thank you very much for the help!

[www.theshepherdnovel.com](https://www.theshepherdnovel.com)

Here is parent component:

```
    import Email from '../components/Email';
import Form from '../components/Form';

//add a state value for alert for when form is submitted success/error
function Call2Action() {
  const getFormData = formData => {
    fetch(
      'https://theshepherd-77005-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/formData.json',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application-json',
        },
      }
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="bg-orange-600">
      <section
        className="w-[100vw] max-w-[1200px] mx-auto h-[100vh] bg-orange-600 text-center
    xs:h-[110vh] 
    sm:h-[112vh]
    xp:h-[103vh]
    ms:h-[120vh]
    mx:h-[92vh]
    ll:h-[150vh]
    xx:h-[138vh]
    rr:h-[122vh]"
      >
        <div
          className="pt-2 text-2xl font-semibold 
      mx:text-3xl "
        >
          <h2>Readers Area</h2>
        </div>
        <h3
          className="text-center p-2
      xp:mb-2
      sm:text-lg "
        >
          Please provide your name and email if you would like to be notified of
          future releases.
        </h3>
        <Form getFormData={getFormData} />
        <div
          className="pt-4
      xp:pt-8"
        >
          <Email />
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Call2Action;
```

And the two child components one after the other:

```
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Button from '../ui/Button';
// import Input from '../ui/Input';
import Alert from './Alert';

function Form({ getFormData }) {
  const nameRef = useRef();
  const emailRef = useRef();
  const [submitting, isSubmitting] = useState(false);
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState({
    show: false,
    msg: '',
    type: '',
  });

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    isSubmitting(true);
    e.preventDefault();

    const name = nameRef.current.value;
    const email = emailRef.current.value;

    const formData = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
    };

    console.log(formData);
    nameRef.current.value = '';
    emailRef.current.value = '';
    getFormData(formData);
    isSubmitting(false);
    showAlert('success', 'Results submitted', true);
  };

  const showAlert = (type = '', msg = '', show = false) => {
    setAlert({ show: show, type: type, msg: msg });
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="bg-amber-500 w-[90vw] h-[20vh] max-w-lg mx-auto p-2 text-center rounded-md
    xs:h-[22vh]
    xp:h-[20vh]
    ms:h-[23vh]
    ll:h-[36vh]
    xx:h-[30vh]
    rr:h-[28vh]
    "
    >
      <form
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        className="p-2 bg-orange-300 h-[18vh]  rounded-md
        xs:h-[20vh]
        xp:h-[18vh]
        ms:h-[21vh]
        ll:h-[33vh]
        xx:h-[27.5vh]
        rr:h-[25.5vh]
        "
      >
        {alert.show && <Alert {...alert} showAlert={showAlert} />}
        <div className="mb-2 p-1 flex justify-center">
          <label
            htmlFor="name"
            className="sm:text-lg
          mx:text-xl mx:mt-4"
          >
            Name:
          </label>
          &nbsp;
          <input
            className="w-[80%] rounded-lg indent-1 bg-orange-100
            sm:text-lg
            mx:text-xl mx:mt-4"
            type="text"
            name="name"
            id="name"
            placeholder="Enter Name"
            required
            minLength="4"
            ref={nameRef}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="p-1 flex justify-center mx:mt-4">
          <label
            className="sm:text-lg
          mx:text-xl"
            htmlFor="email"
          >
            Email:{' '}
          </label>
          &nbsp;
          <input
            className="w-[80%] rounded-lg indent-1 bg-orange-100
            sm:text-lg 
            mx:text-xl"
            type="email"
            name="email"
            id="email"
            placeholder="Enter Email"
            required
            ref={emailRef}
          />
        </div>
        {!alert.show && (
          <Button
            className="text-center bg-orange-600 rounded-lg shadow-md px-3 py-1  mt-2 shadow-orange-500 hover:scale-110 active:scale-100 cursor-pointer transition-all text-xl tracking-wider text-orange-300 font-semibold
            xp:mt-3
            sm:mt-2
            mx:text-xl mx:mt-8
            xx:mt-4
          "
            type="submit"
            disabled={submitting}
          >
            Submit
          </Button>
        )}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form;

import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';
import Button from '../ui/Button';

const Email = () => {
  function sendEmail(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs
      .sendForm(
        'HIDDEN',
        'template_5kfpbfh',
        e.target,
        'HIDDEN'
      )
      .then(res => {
        window.location.href = '/';
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
  return (
    <div
      className="bg-orange-600 h-[30rem]    max-w-xl mx-auto
      
    "
    >
      <h2
        className="text-xl mb-1
      xp:mb-2
      sm:text-2xl
      ms:-mt-4
      ll:mt-0"
      >
        Email the Author
      </h2>
      <form
        onSubmit={sendEmail}
        className="w-[90vw] max-w-lg p-2 bg-orange-300 mx-auto h-[26rem]  border-amber-500 border-4 rounded-md
        sm:text-lg sm:h-[29.5rem]"
      >
        <div className="p-2 flex justify-center">
          <label htmlFor="name">Name:&nbsp;</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            id="name"
            placeholder="Name"
            className="rounded-lg indent-1 w-[80%] bg-orange-100"
            required
            minLength="4"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex justify-center p-2">
          <label htmlFor="email">Email:&nbsp;</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="email"
            id="email"
            placeholder="Email"
            className="rounded-lg indent-1 w-[80%] bg-orange-100"
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex justify-center p-2">
          <textarea
            name="message"
            id="message"
            cols="35"
            rows="10"
            className="rounded-md indent-1 bg-orange-100
            "
            placeholder="Write message here..."
          ></textarea>
        </div>

        <Button
          className="px-3 py-1 text-center rounded-lg shadow-lg   mt-2 shadow-orange-500 hover:scale-110 active:scale-100 cursor-pointer transition-all text-xl tracking-wider bg-orange-600 text-orange-300 font-semibold
          xp:py-2 xp:px-4"
          type="submit"
        >
          Send
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Email;
```